# javascript redefine prototype using existing prototype

Tags: javascript, debugging, prototype

I would like to redefine a prototype, but still use the original prototype function. The purpose is to add test bench debug code to an existing production prototype definition.

```
// production definition
function tester(n) { this.name = n ; }
tester.prototype.getName = function() { return this.name; }

// debug override
if (typeof tester.prototype.getName === 'function') {
  var f = tester.prototype.getName;
  tester.prototype.getName = function () {
    return f() + " (plus some more)";
  };
}

// test
var tt = new tester('testing');
console.log(tt.getName());  // logs ' (plus some more)' but I want 'testing (plus some more)'
```

Naturally, my production prototypes are much more complex, and I would rather not embed my test bench code in the production code.

Many thanks in advance! - John :)

Comment: i would look into a function tool that offers the ability to _compose_, i think lodash has one. that way, you can mix and match extended capabilities without hand-coding each interception.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `f` with the correct `this` value and the correct arguments:

```
f.apply(this, arguments);
```

Learn more about [**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

---

This seems to be a very fragile approach though because it also requires you to know what kind of value the original method returns and what calling code is doing with it.

But I guess you are only doing this for very specific methods.

Answer (score 0):

In your redefinition, you need to set the proper context (`this`) for the `f` function using `Function.prototype.apply()`.  In your code, the context of the `f` function is set to the global scope, even when it is called in the redefined getName property of `tt`.  Instead, it should be the context of the redefined getName function.

```
// production definition
function tester(n) { this.name = n ; }
tester.prototype.getName = function() { return this.name; }

// debug override
if (typeof tester.prototype.getName === 'function') {
  var f = tester.prototype.getName;
  // Here, 'this' is the global scope (window).
  console.log('Global scope:');
  console.log(this);  
  console.log('f called with context of global scope:');
  console.log(f()); // prints 'name' prop of global scope
  tester.prototype.getName = function () {
    console.log("Instance:");
    console.log(this);
    // Here, 'this' is tt when tt.getName() is evaluated.
    // If we call f() here, the context for f 
    // will still be the global scope, instead of tt.
    // So, we use apply to set the context of f to 
    // an instance of tester.
    return f.apply(this) + " (plus some more)";  
  };
}

// test
var tt = new tester('testing');
console.log(tt.getName());  // logs testing (plus some more)'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a27xzqc9/3/

Comment: So, what's the solution you are suggesting and how is it different from mine?

Comment: It's the same solution, I believe.

Comment: Why did you post it then?

Comment: I was busy coding it up in the jsfiddle.  I think being able to play with it helps one understand how context is set when getName is called in the last line of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Extending Felix and Patrick's answer with encapsulation to avoid using the global variable "f", since I will be reusing this structure several times.

```
;(function(){
  if (typeof tester.prototype.getName === 'function') {
    var f = tester.prototype.getName;
    tester.prototype.getName = function () {
      return f.apply(this) + " (plus some more)";
    };
  }
})();
```